# Liquibase set column default value to null

Tags: mysql, null, liquibase, default-value

I tried with liquibase to set the default value of my column to null with liquibase "addDefaultValue" syntax:

```
<changeSet id="20181213171501-2">
    <!-- Add default value -->
    <addDefaultValue tableName="myTable"
        columnDataType="boolean"
        columnName="myColumn"
        defaultValueBoolean="null" />
</changeSet>
```

But inserting a new row to myTable showed that the default value was still set to 'false', as before. So liquibase changeset didn't work.

How to set a column default value to null with liquibase?

Comment: Removing the line `defaultValueBoolean="null"` resulted in `liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed: defaultValue is required, Default value of null does not match defined type of boolean` even if the column is nullable

Answer (score 2):

That exactly what the [dropDefaultValue](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/drop_default_value.html) refactoring does: it resets the default value of nullable columns to null.

```
<changeSet id="20181213171501-2">
    <!-- Reset default value to NULL -->
    <dropDefaultValue tableName="myTable" columnName="mColumn" />
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to use a raw SQL query instead of liquibase "addDefaultValue" syntax:

```
<changeSet id="20181213171501-2">
    <!-- Add default value -->
    <sql dbms="mysql">
        ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY myColumn BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT NULL
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```