# How to set liquibase column default value if value is null

Tags: null, liquibase, default-value

I have an optional value that I want to add to a column. As the value is optional, I want the default value to be false, if the value is null. I have tried several options, but none of them is working for me. Is it even possible or do I have to do an explicit update? Leaving out the nullable-constraint results in having the value null in the entry, if the value is missing. Adding the constraint results in a violation of the constraint obviously. But in none of the cases, the default value is set, if the value is null.

```
<column name="colName" type="BOOLEAN" defaultValueBoolean="false">
  <constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
```

Comment: Did you see this earlier post on StackOverflow about the same thing? There are a couple of answers there that might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781733/liquibase-set-column-default-value-to-null